# Is it possible to masquerade a packet on a bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, bridge, masquerade

I have a container which has an incoming VPN. A connection into that container will be assigned the `192.168.10.10` IP. The virtual NIC of the container has an IP of `10.10.10.1` and a gateway (on the host bridge) of `10.10.10.254`.

When directly logged into the container, a packet will leave with `10.10.10.1` as the source and will know how to come back (via the bridge).

When VPNed-in, the packet leaves with `192.168.10.10` as the source and would not come back as `192.168.10.x` is not advertized in the network (there is no route to that network).

There are two solutions to this:

- either masquerade in the container so that the packet leaves with `10.10.10.1`
- or advertize the `192.168.10.x` route on the network

I would like (for various reasons) avoid going for either of these solutions and was wondering **if it is possible to do the masquerading in the bridge itself**, on the host side?
In other words a packet would be leaving the container with a source of `192.168.10.10`, which would then be rewritten "by the bridge" to a known `10.10.10.1` IP (and then rewritten again when the reply comes back to the container)

Note: how to do it in `shorewall` would be awesome but any information will be great.

Answer (score 1):

For shorewall, you can edit /etc/shorewall/masq, to look something like:

`br0            192.168.10.1/24     -       tcp 22,80,443`

You will also need to create an entry in /etc/shorewall/hosts and /etc/shorewall/zones for the VPN range, and of course add any necessary rules to /etc/shorewall/rules.

However, I think you might have a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

If I understand your setup correctly, *only* your container knows about the `192.168.10/24` range.

Meaning the issue wouldn't actually be solved (only) by using masquerading.

The problem is that the host on which the container is running also does not have a route for 192.168.10/24, because that route only exists within the container's routing table.

So, at minimum, you would need:

- a route on your container host pointing towards your container( e.g. `ip r add 192.168.10.1/24 via 10.10.10.1`)
- then add the masq rule in shorewall.

Otherwise, your container host sees what amounts to martians coming from your VPN container.

Answer (score 1):

The `MASQUERADE` iptables target operates in the `POSTROUTING` table, which is only used for packets routed from one interface to another. The bridged packets are probably not accessed at IP-Level at any time, so you won't be able to masquerade them.